# When Do We Get Co-ed Showers?

Tags: society, gender, near-future

There are many sci-fi stories that feature this: a shower or locker room occupied by both men and women, in various states of indecency. I'm sure it all began when someone wanted more nudity in their movie or something like that, but I've been thinking. These days, people are becoming more and more accepting of new ideas of gender and sexuality, many of which reject the male-female binary. It's plausible that some day, the idea of men/women bathrooms would seem just as crazy as the white/colored bathrooms we used to have. Even now, when I see two single-occupancy bathrooms, I realize that it would be almost twice as useful if they were general-use.

So, as far as I'm concerned, sharing bathrooms/locker rooms/showers is something that *should* happen; what I'm wondering is when it *will* happen. Are there any indications that this change is right around the corner, or suggestions that we will never move past our current state of modesty? Any places that might spearhead the effort, or vehemently oppose it?

Comment: Probably when men stop excitedly asking. You've just set us back a bit.

Comment: @Samuel Good point. You have my deepest apologies.

Comment: "These days, people are becoming more and more accepting of new ideas of gender and sexuality, many of which reject the male-female binary." And pretty much all of those people are exclusive to niche websites. The vast majority of the current human population will give you weird looks and/or roll their eyes if you try telling them stuff about a "gender spectrum". If co-ed bathrooms were to become a normal sight, I'd imagine it'd be for a practical reason, not a cultural one. Heck, disabled toilets are already co-ed.

Comment: @Pyritie Except that it isn't. The really off the wall ones, like "I self identify as a stapler" are rather niche. But the mainstream of "I don't identify as a man, I identify as a male" are rather widespread.

Comment: @corsiKa: San Francisco and tumblr do not count as "widespread".

Comment: There is more to it than just San Francisco. Dozens of countries (Australia, Germany and India to name a couple) have official recognition of non-binary genders, and all support for it is within the last 15 years which indicates it's the beginning of a movement. Given Germany's influence in the EU, and France's influence as well as their open views on sexuality, it is very likely you'll see non-binary status recognized in most European countries in the next 20 years.

Comment: @corsiKa is correct. This is a very common (and widely accepted) thing outside of the southern United States.

Comment: @corsiKa that sounds like the beginnings of a pretty good answer. If you want to post it as such (maybe with some sources or more examples), I'd definitely upvote it, and maybe even accept it.

Comment: @Samuel: As someone who lives in a very progressive city in the northern United States, I disagree. It's more common, but still not common. And definitely not "widely accepted".

Comment: @AndrewCoonce There are still pockets of bigotry, of course. Wisconsin, while I've never heard of any part of it being described as "very progressive" (though I don't doubt it at all, look at Austin, Texas), is barely out of the bible belt. So, I'm not surprised by your observations. Do you have that joke where you say the only thing wrong with Madison is that it's surrounded by Wisconsin?

Comment: I'm not a sauna goes myself, but AFAIK mixed gender saunas aren't uncommon in Germany.

Comment: @Samuel: I think you're looking for "Madison: 77 square miles surrounded by reality". Madison is frequently mentioned with cities like Austin and Portland, but even here there's probably ~40% chance that a given person will here "I'm a trans-whatever" and unconsciously roll their eyes.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not headed the **other** way.  It seems more and more that showers in locker rooms, etc. are becoming more and more: "doesn't matter gender - but I want my own room/stall".

Comment: @Mikey I agree completely. For the general public this is certainly the case. I think the co-ed thing mainly appears in films depicting the military (actually Starship Troopers is the only example I can think of right now). The military has an agenda concerning individuality, so forcing everyone to look the same, sleep in the same room, and shower in the same room just serves that agenda.

Comment: @Samuel As for appearances, I can think of Starship Troopers, the reboot of Battlestar Galactica, Robocop, and maybe Alien(s). So yeah, mostly a military theme.

Comment: @Samuel Wisconsin is so far north of the bible belt that it hasn't even seen it for the past 20 years due to the large belly it has developed in the form of Illinois, Indiana, Ohio, Kentucky, and half of West Virginia and Tennessee. Any farther north and you'll literally be in Canada.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about predictions for social norms in the real world, not about world building as defined by the scope of the help center.

Comment: @TylerH You may be right, though I promise it is for worldbuilding purposes.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh In that case I would recommend editing the question so that it is asked within the context of building a world.

Comment: It will be 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @Samuel Well, I can honestly say that pretty much every Mormon area of the US doesn't really approve of gays or "third gender" people, but it is less discrimination than just weird looks and a little bit of avoidance. I mean, I think people need to accept emotionally, mentally, and physically that here are literally two genders. Male and female. Deal with it.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Wrong. There are literally two *sexes*, but *gender* is far less of a dichotomy. You can disagree as much as you like, but it's not your business to tell other people what gender they can or cannot identify with. Deal with that, or don't, it doesn't matter to the facts. Who cares what the Mormons think about sexuality anyway?

Comment: @Samuel Before I continue this argument, let me just say I am a lot more forceful with my opinions and the truth than most, while also a lot more argumentative. So don't judge others based on me. I'm not telling you what you can or can't do, I couldn't care less. I'm Just stating facts. Male or Female.

Answer (score 14):

Although some clubs and venues which target alternative lifestyles have already adopted shared bathrooms, it is unlikely that this heralds a universal change throughout our culture.

The issue is not solely one of modesty.  Functionality also plays its part.  Single gender areas serve many purposes beyond their biological and hygenic functions.  They provide a sanctuary from undesired pursuit and a place of privacy for planning out a next move.  These roles are left unfilled when bathrooms are shared.

As for spearheads, I think that sharing will start in military vessels where gender specific facilities are a waste of space which could otherwise be used for weapons and supplies.

And vehemently opposed, will be churches ...and hopefully, obesity clinics.

Comment: This should be a comment. True, it addresses *some* of the question, but as it stands this is a mere speculative observation which doesn't cover most of what is asked.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm sorry but I have to disagree. "Your assumption is wrong" is a perfectly good answer, especially if it bothers to explain in detail why it is.

Comment: @Lohoris it wasn't this long before. Previously, it was a one liner. I don't know if you can see the previous edit though...

Comment: @Aify good catch!

Comment: @Lohoris Indeed, Aify is right. Click the "edited ... mins ago" link to see the previous revision.

Comment: Sorry if my edits caused a bit of confusion.  When @ArtOfCode made his initial comment, suggesting that my answer was too short, I fleshed it out in reponse.  I only had time for the one-liner initially, and should have put that in a comment as AOC suggested.  Once done however, I figured it was better to fix what was wrong then to leave it the way it was.

Comment: @HenryTaylor No problem, you've made this a good answer now. Have 10 internet points.

Answer (score 6):

It seem to me more of a case of culture and attitudes towards sex more than anything else. There's a few ways you could have it happen.

1) Space born adaption. They've spent there whole life in space and room is at a premium.

2) Massive social upheaval. Some extreme event (like nuclear war) has caused massive change to cultural norms. Like the setting being a police state that watches its people 24/7.

3) Something happened to make normal sex taboo and/or disgusting. The best candidate would be everyone being test tube babies who's genes are tampered with as a matter of normality.

In all the above you really need at least a generation or two I think for it to become 'normal think'.

Answer (score 6):

Why would people generally object to co-ed showers?

Most societies value faithfulness in monogamous relationships. Faithfulness helps to raise children, which helps to perpetuate the society. As a result, the society discourages the display of primary and secondary sexual characteristics in public. (Consider that it may be appropriate for males to bare their chest in situations where that would be inappropriate for females, e.g. on the beach.)

The display of sexual characteristics is *less* inappropriate in groups of the same gender. I guess this shows an assumption that they're not "tempting" each other.

So to create the culture you're describing, you have to explain why those constraints are gone. Are heterosexual families no longer the main way to raise children?

Comment: You changed from saying "monogamous relationships" being the best thing for children to "heterosexual families" being the best thing. Your implied deficiency of same sex parents with all else being the same is unsupported and generally offensive.

Comment: @Samuel, let's not be so quick to judge. o.m didn't say heterosexual was best. What I think om is implying is that if heterosexual parenting is no longer the standard in society and same sex marriage is welcomed with open arms, then the idea that we need separate male/female bathrooms would be moot if two men in the bathrooms could be turned on by each other.  Thus, what I think om is suggesting is that in such a society just mix up men and women together since it's possible people in the showers will still find someone to be attracted to.  Hope my interpretation is correct...

Comment: @jmort253 The current system divides on sex lines, not gender lines, which has nothing to do with parenting. Perhaps I'm not seeing the point trying to be made, but as it stands I've downvoted this answer, which can be reversed if the point is made clear.

Comment: @Samuel, individuals who look after their own offspring are more likely to pass their genes to the next generation, especially for species with a K-selection strategy. Same sex parents have decided to go against their biological programming -- humans do that all the time, we're a sapient species and not a finite-state automaton. But more parents will decide to go with their programming. For that reason I believe that heterosexual families will remain the most common type, the default type.

Comment: What a silly statement, of course they're more likely to pass on their genes if they've already done so. Parenting, same sex couples or not, is not going against their biological programming. Heterosexual couples will likely remain most common, but it's not due to some deficiency of programming for same sex couples. Are you serious with this?

Comment: @samuel, Om didn't say it was a deficiency in programming just that it goes against the perceived biological nature of humans to procreate and then have deep, strong feelings for those offspring. Sure, same sex couples and hetero parents who adopt can feel strongly about their kids, but I think it's possible that could be the exception and not the norm.  Do the same chemicals flood these folks brains that would flood a mother's brain who carried her child in her womb for 9 months?

Comment: @jmort253 The particular hormonal changes in a birth mother are irrelevant. The adoption bonding is the same as for a father and his child and [clearly works just fine](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/109/2/341.short). I still don't see what sexual orientation has to do with parenting or what that has to do with co-ed showers. Why was it even brought up? It's totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Samuel "The particular hormonal changes in a birth mother are irrelevant. "  Are you sure about this?  What a silly statement!

Comment: @NPSF3000 Many statements become silly out of context. For the context and conversation the statement was made in, yes, I'm sure about that. Does the love of the adopting parents depend on the hormonal changes in the birth mother? No, it's irrelevant. You might consider defaulting to *not* commenting on something you don't understand and were not involved in originally.

Comment: @Samuel That's excellent advice.  All I see from you appears to be indignation and strongly worded statements, neither of which actually give any credence to your position.  But since you would like to keep this discussion private (obviously dissenting voices is too difficult for you to manage).  I'll leave you to have you soapbox.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Ha, yes, nice try. Sorry to hurt your feelings (welcome to the internet!). In the future, you're welcome to participate in conversations if you understand what's going on and actually have something to add. Even if it's a six week old dead question.

Comment: @Samuel: "Unsupported..." unless you, oh, I don't know, maybe look at the *decades of solid research* providing support for that position?  (Sorry to hurt your feelings. Welcome to the Internet.)

Comment: @masonwheeler You say there is decades of solid research showing the deficiency of same sex parents? That's false, you misunderstood either the research or what you're commenting on. Your misunderstanding does not hurt my feelings though, thanks :)

Comment: @Samuel: There's decades of solid research showing "the deficiency of" both growing up without a father and growing up without a mother, and also that either one does a really poor job of replacing the other.  Put together, it works out to the same thing.

Comment: @masonwheeler Ah, a misunderstanding of the research then. Honestly, far more moronic than I was expecting. Nice work.

Comment: Yes, because anyone who disagrees with your position must obviously be "moronic".  I wish I could say that was somehow worse than I was expecting, but sadly it's all too typical.

Answer (score 6):

Except in the case of massive social upheaval, I think co-ed showers will never be the standard. As @Samuel said jokingly in a comment:

> Probably when men stop excitedly asking.

This is quite a humorous comment, but there's a much more serious way to put it - separate bathrooms and showers will always be around as long as rape is still a thing. One rape is all it can take to bring a costly lawsuit down on the heads of whatever organization owns the building.

The only place for co-ed showers is one in which everyone using them feels safe. It's hard to imagine a society in which every single woman feels comfortable having men be able to see them naked without the woman being able to do much about it. Men can also be victims in situations like this - there are male victims of rape.

Co-ed showers can be put in place in limited locations, such as the "clubs and venues which target alternative lifestyles" that @HenryTaylor mentioned. The people that go there expect it, and choose to use them because they still feel safe there.

I wouldn't be surprised if society moves in the opposite direction that you're thinking - rather than having a single co-ed shower, we'll have more single-occupancy showers. It doesn't make as much sense from an efficiency standpoint, but *what is there about legal issues that would make you think efficiency is anywhere on their minds?* Also think about this question - how can the mother of a 6 year-old girl tell the difference between an honest transgendered person and a committed pedophile man? The best way for a facility to protect itself from lawsuits from both the mother protecting her child and a transgendered person wanting to use the bathroom they think is the right one for them would be to have single-occupancy and family bathrooms.

Even space constraints alone won't bring about co-ed showers - if you have enough room for two showers, there's no reason you can't have a divider between them that turns it into two bathrooms. So you've either got a single-occupancy bathroom, or enough room for more than one.

A dystopian government, like the one @MrDracoSpirit mentioned, might impose co-ed showers on certain groups of undesirables, but I would not count that as becoming a standard. That government would need to keep enough people happy to prevent a complete revolt, and those people would not be forced into co-ed showers. So rather than becoming a standard, co-ed showers would be seen as a sort of punishment.

@MrDracoSpirit's third point is something that would definitely make co-ed showers likely. If culture lost interest in sex, then rape would most likely stop being a thing. And that, as I said earlier, is something that would make co-ed showers reasonable.

Comment: Costly lawsuits are mainly a thing of western culture. In India, for instance, no one worries about lawsuits because they just aren't rampant like they are, for instance, in the USA...  I also think that rape is more common in societies where there exists sexual shame, such as India and the USA.  In countries where sex isn't shameful or taboo, I think we find that rape or assault on women is less...

Comment: Oh man, I was only considering the juvenile giggling that would occur, not this predatory interpretation. I would think that both would be far less common when the whole imposed "mystery" of the opposite sex is not given so much importance. There appears to be a correlation between sexual oppression and rape, [for instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church_sexual_abuse_cases).

Comment: When I was a kid I remember hearing that bathrooms in Europe were already unisex.  Not sure if that's true or not, but I often wonder, if it were true, if the giggling would just be passed off as giggling about any other physical or social characteristics, like making fun of someone's haircut.  In some societies that haven't been westernized, women sometimes run around with their breasts exposed, implying that they aren't ashamed and if someone were to say something about them in their society, I wonder how she would interpret it.  Maybe she'd just laugh it off? Thought provoking...

Comment: @Samuel I wish it could be just juvenile giggling. It's not a fun subject, but it's a real one that should be addressed.

Answer (score 4):

This is a totally anecdotal, but interesting none the less. When the Youtube Space LA was build it had to be a forward thinking space, etc. etc. So instead of having the toilets separated by gender they indeed had non-segregated restrooms. Well, it was kept that way for awhile and what happened? Males made a huge mess half the time, females hated going to the restrooms due to this and they ended up segregating the different stalls as a 'fix' in the end. So at the very least I guess it's valid to conclude that: No, at the very least it's not around the corner for restrooms.

Comment: This is the negative segregation I'm talking about. Why must men be forced to use the less clean restrooms? Why can't I, as a relatively clean and courteous individual, have access to the cleaner female facilities? We're not fixing the problem, we're just prolonging the stereotype that men are slobs. But yeah, that's a good point.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Well, the reality of the matter is that sexes are one of the most useful and objective differentiators between humans. I mean, there is a lot of backslash against it nowadays, but still a persons sex tells you more about his abilities, strengths, weaknesses and habits than any other easily observable attribute.

Comment: I agree men and women are different on average, it just sucks that we have to draw the line so arbitrarily (or at all), when really humans exist on more of a spectrum. And I think it's more of a self-fulfilling prophecy: men develop manly habits because they spend so much time with other men. I don't think many men would be so messy if they'd never used a men's restroom before.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh 1) But we can't make restrooms a spectrum. 2) Modern research is showing more and more that nurture is not the basis of a lot of gender traits. 3) The mess males make are caused to a large extent due to their biological features which I do not need to name explicitly here.

Comment: Have either of you had female roommates? They can be *incredibly* messy. Anecdotally, I've only see that the opposite of this stereotype is true. But then most males I know are engineers (not programmers, those guys *are* messy), so there is a bias in my view.

Comment: @Samuel Never said guys are *generally* messier. I think girls might be slightly cleaner from my experience, but it's definitely not a huge difference like the state of restrooms. Many years ago I had to clean restrooms as a volunteer for a couple of days and the difference between the male and female restrooms was like night and day. Not kidding.

Comment: Now I'm wondering why you voted to close a question you found worth answering.

Comment: @Samuel I noticed the close vote after answering. After considering it I had to agree with it, despite the question being kinda interesting it simply didn't really belong on worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: @Samuel I *asked* the question, and after seeing the close votes I agreed with them. While this was information I wanted to have, and it will help me better understand human society for a story I'm writing, I did not actually phrase the question in a way that makes it a good fit here.